# Unable to locate package phpmyadmin on Ubuntu Server 18.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

Whenever I try to install phpmyadmin on my ubuntu server 18.04 I get the following errors

```
sudo apt install phpmyadmin php-mbstring php-gettext
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package phpmyadmin
E: Unable to locate package php-mbstring
E: Unable to locate package php-gettext
```

Most threads I ca find suggest reupdating and upgrading using apt, but doing so doesn't do anything, also I get that error on the fourth line

```
Err:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nijel/phpmyadmin/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:7 http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge Release
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/nijel/phpmyadmin/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
```

Can someone help with this?

Comment: See this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/866663/cant-install-phpmyadmin-package-cannot-be-located/866666

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 7):

On the Ubuntu Server 18.04 the list of apt sources is rather short and secure. If you want to install phpmyadmin or autossh or number of other packages which are not supported in main sources list, you should adjust the sources list.

```
$ sudo apt edit-sources
```

You can use the following list:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
```

More information can be found here:
[handyman.dulare.com/ubuntu-18-04-bionic-unable-to-locate-package...](https://handyman.dulare.com/ubuntu-18-04-bionic-unable-to-locate-package-when-installing-in-command-line/)